# Latency issue for attending a HTTP request using Netty libary

Tags: netty

We implemented a Server that attends over HTTP/Json requests. Our Netty configuration is a follows:

```
<apg-netty-servers>
        <boss-threads>1</boss-threads>
        <worker-threads>10</worker-threads>
        <worker-blocking-threads>250</worker-blocking-threads>
        <keep-alive>true</keep-alive>
        <high-water-mark>131072</high-water-mark>
        <low-water-mark>2048</low-water-mark>
        <receive-buffer>2097152</receive-buffer>
        <backlog>500</backlog>
        <log-channel>true</log-channel>
        <server name="server-core-ugp">
            <bind-host>0.0.0.0</bind-host>
            <bind-port>2040</bind-port>
            <router-timeout>0</router-timeout>
            <handlers-chain>ugp</handlers-chain>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </server>
</apg-netty-servers>
```

We noticed that with high volume (TPS) the requests that are sent to the Server doesn´t reject with a 500 or similar response error code instead the requests are attended with high lattency, sometimes of a couple of minutes, wondering if any parameters could generate this behaviour generating a kind fo queue to be attended and when the worker threads are free take from there the request to be proccessed?

We implemented a jmeter test, we expect that if the Server is fully occupied we get rejections instead of this kind of latency issue.